# Cannot Retrieve Data From Access Database

Tags: java, ms-access

I am trying to create an java web application. In  that application i create a servlet to retrieve data from MS-Access database. I did this so many times in our laboratory but now i cant. I dont know what is the reason. Here is my processRequest method:

**ProcessRequest**

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String des=request.getParameter("desc");
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wsds","","");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Table1 where wsdesc="+des);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String description=rs.getString("wsdesc");
            String url=rs.getString("url");
            out.println(description);
            out.println(url);
        }

    } finally {   
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I use Netbeans 7.0.1 IDE. I create a datasource wsds. I check the table column names are correct. Anyone can help me??

Comment: Any errors ? Stacktrace?

Comment: you trying to access MS-access. what have you written in `Class.forname`

Comment: Please use `catch()`. Atleast you will know whether it executed properly or threw 'SQLException'

Comment: **(1)** Try commenting out the `Class.forName` statement. Under most circumstances it is no longer required. **(2)** You are injecting user data directly into an SQL statement, leaving you vulnerable to SQL Injection problems. You may also not be quoting your `wsdesc` value correctly. Both problems would go away if you used a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I cant add catch after the try block. It shows an error the corresponding Exception is not thrown in the try body.

Comment: I just changed this line as follows. I got the answer

   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Table1 where wsdesc="+"'"+des+"'");

Answer (score 1):

change

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Table1 where wsdesc="+des);
```

to

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Table1 where wsdesc='"+des+"'");
```

Varchar datatypes should be enclosed with `'` `'`

Instead of Statement use PreparedStatement

```
PreparedStatement pt=con.prepareStatement("select * from Table1 where wsdesc=?");
pt.setString(1,desc);
ResultSet rs=pt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: @GordThompson OP is using statement so I gave the solution in Statement.I have also provided alternative using preparedstatement

Answer (score 0):

Update the driver name as

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

Comment: @VinayakPingale i dnt think sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection driver exist

Comment: After I change JdbcOdbcConnection to JdbcOdbcDriver it doesn't display anything.

Comment: @user3243259 you need to put the varchar inside '',see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Table1 where wsdesc='"+des+"'");
```